# How to create smart contract using openzeppelin metatx relayer to receive and withdraw usdt erc20 token using metamask?

Tags: solidity, ether, metamask, openzeppelin, meta-transactions

Here is what I need to do,

1. Create a smart contract that can use a relayer account from Openzeppelin defender and do the gasless meta transactions. Which I already created and sent some Ethereum too.
2. The contract can receive **USDT** *erc20* funds, and show balance, and the contract owner can withdraw the funds.
3. Then use Metamask in a react frontend and call those functions. Here the Metamask account will not pay the gas fees. Instead, the relayer will do.

The contract I created,

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract EtherWallet{
    address payable public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner =payable(msg.sender);
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function withdraw(uint _amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can withdraw");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amount);

    }

    function getBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

But not sure how to do this. I need help with all the 3 options.

Comment: Did you manage to do this?